# WCF hosting issues

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Hi I wonder if someone can help me, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to solve this but no luck yet :( I have a WCF hosted on IIS6 on a remote server on our internal network, http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc. I can access the service in my browser, however when trying to send a request using WcfTestClient, i get the following error:

```
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
> http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc If this is a Windows
> (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
> check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
> address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
> MSDN documentation at
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
> Error    URI: http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc   
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> 'http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc'.    There was no
> endpoint listening at http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc
> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
> address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
> details.    Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it
> 172.16.25.221:80HTTP GET Error    URI: http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc    There was an error
> downloading 'http://systemservices/ServiceManagerServices.svc'.   
> Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it 172.16.25.221:80
```

I have tried changing my web.config to so many different values it is untrue, however nothing! Any ideas would be really welcome!!!

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ServiceManager.Services.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="ServiceManager.Services.ServiceManagerServices" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceManager.Services.IServiceManagerServices" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't connect, it could be an access restriction, but this message can show when you've been kicked back for other issues, so this could be a missing referenced binary, or use of an invalid `DataContract` or something similar.

Firstly, turn on some diagnostics:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="path\to\trace.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

Now run the service, get the error and using [SvcTraceTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) (just go to `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs` and do a search for `svc`) open up the output log. This will give you more of an overview of the process, at which point it goes wrong and point to more details of the exception - sometimes just telling you to look in the Event Log for the specific exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 172.16.25.221:80

I would say it is a firewall issue, not a web.config issue. Can you telnet to that address on port 80 and get a response?