# Returning an Image from OperationContract method (WCF service)

Tags: c#, wcf, image

I'm trying to get an `Image` from a WCF service.

I have an `OperationContract` function that returns an `Image` to the client, but when I call it from the client, 
I get this exception:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9619978'.

Client:

```
private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picBox.Picture = client.GetScreenShot();
}
```

Service.cs:

```
public Image GetScreenShot()
{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width,bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

`IScreenShot` Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IScreenShot
{
    [OperationContract]
    System.Drawing.Image GetScreenShot();
}
```

So why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You may want to take a look at WCF [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: @JoshuaDrake i previously read about it, but i couldn't understand it all, i only understood that i should use Streamed instead of buffered if i want to transfer a large amount of data! but is that it, i change buffered to streamed then i got the Image?

Comment: Can you try to change the image format to jpg rather than png. At times streaming png has issues.

Comment: nope, the problem when i return an image which is not supported by WCF service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured it out.

- First use `TransferMode.Streamed` or `StreamedResponse` (depends on your need).
- Return the stream, and don't forget to set `Stream.Postion = 0` so you start reading the stream from the beginning.

In the service:

```
public Stream GetStream()
{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Position = 0;  // This is very important
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IScreenShot
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetStream();
}
```

On the client side:

```
public partial class ScreenImage: Form
{
    ScreenShotClient client;
    public ScreenImage(string baseAddress)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        client = new ScreenShotClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(client.GetStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, can i ask you a question about code above? What is 'img' in code line "img = Image.FromStream(ms);"?

Comment: @NguyễnHuy Sorry I didn't see this comment until now, I forgot to remove it, It's fixed now

Answer (score 3):

You can use Stream to return large data/Images.

[Sample Example(returning Image as Stream) from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define something that is serializable. `System.Drawing.Image` is, but not in the context of WCF (using `DataContractSerializer`) by default. That could range from returning the raw bytes as an array, or serialization to a string (base64, JSON) or implementing a [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) that is serializable and can carry the data with it.

As others have said, WCF supports streaming, but that's not the crux of the issue here. Depending on the size of the data you might wish to do this, and doing so will reduce the problem in itself since you would be streaming bytes (from an evident, top-level view).

You could also [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737399/wcf-hosting-issues/9737481#9737481) to help you get the at the actual exception details, like a full stacktrace instead of just the fault info.

Comment: so i need to declare a new class that holds the image and return it to the client?

Comment: I would, or an alternative as suggested. I wouldn't try pushing down an Image instance by hook or by crook.

Comment: i want to avoid using Sockets to receive the Image, i want to return it in a nice way, do you have a good idea?